# Why I have to use double ../ when using __dir__ in this case

Tags: php, path

File Paths

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zcron\x.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\zzz\config.php
```

I am including config file into x.php file. To include the config file I need to go one directory back outside zcron directory.

So this works

```
`require '../zzz/db/config.php'`;
```

but when I use

```
require __dir__.'../zzz/db/config.php';
```

It gives me an error saying

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\zcron../zzz/db/config.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\zcron\x.php on line 2
```

If i use double ../ then it works

```
<?php 
require __dir__.'../../zzz/db/config.php';
require '../zzz/db/config.php';
?>
```

Echoing `__dir__` in my case outputs
`C:\xampp\htdocs\zcron` which means I have to go one directory back so why single ../ doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot the slash between the dirname and the dot-dot. Look at the error, it's your clue! It just "happens to work" under Windows with your extra dot-dot because dots at the end of a filename are dropped (`zcron..` is handled like `zcron`).

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zcron/../zzz/db/config.php
                     ^
                     (this slash was missing)
```

So the solution is to use `__dir__.'/../stuff'` and not `__dir__.'../stuff'`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have an error in your syntax
add '/' befor '..'
I think it will works

```
<?php 
require __dir__.'/../zzz/db/config.php';
require '../zzz/db/config.php';
?>
```

Comment: _I think it will works..._ **Why** do you think so?

Comment: because I notice he has error in his syntax. so form my point of view after fixing this syntax I think that solution will work.

Comment: _... I notice he has error in his syntax...._ But **what**  error? A good answer needs a good explanation ;)

Comment: _..please teach me..._ I am not here to teach you anything and there is no need to be unfriendly or unkind. You are expected to have gone through the guide line tours of StackOverflow before posting answers. Take a look at [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It is not a good answer when you say "I think it works" or "I saw your error" without mentioning the error and telling **why** your answer is the solution. _...If you have any solution then post in answer..._ There is no need for that as @CherryDT just gave the correct answer.

Comment: I will take back my downvote after you have edited the answer in a proper way :)